# group gps data on haversine distance and calculate the mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe like following (cannot show from original due to NDA):

```
points = [(-57.213878612138828, 17.916958304169601),
          (76.392039480378514, 0.060882542482108504),
          (0.12417670682730897, 1.0417670682730924),
          (-64.840321976787706, 21.374279296143762),
          (-48.966302937359913, 81.336323778066188),
          (11.122014925372399, 85.001119402984656),
          (8.6383049769438465, 84.874829066623917),
          (-57.349835526315836, 16.683634868421084),
          (83.051530302006697, 97.450469562867383),
          (8.5405200433369473, 83.566955579631625),
          (81.620435769843965, 48.106831247886376),
          (78.713027357450656, 19.547209139192304),
          (82.926153287322933, 81.026080639302577)]

x = [i[0] for i in points]
y = [i[1] for i in points]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y)), columns =['lat', 'lon'])
df
```

[image]
[image]
I want to cluster/group all points where distance <= 400 and after I want to calculate the mean of each group -- PLEASE NO CLUSTERING TECHNIQUE - ONLY HARD CODED:

What I have done is - first wrote the haversine funtion:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
import pandas as pd


def haversine(lon1,lat1, lon2,lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lat1, lon1 = lon1,lat1
    lat2, lon2 = lon2,lat2
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r
```

Then I have wrote a function to combine all the gps data - without recurrings - is that a MISTAKE?

```
def pairs(number):
    list_num = []
    for i in range(number):
        for j in range(number):
            if j >= i+1:
                list_num.append([i,j])
    return list_num

pair_list = pairs(12)
print(pair_list)
```

[image]

**!!!HERE HELP NEEDED!!!**
In the following code I tried to implement the code using a dictionary but I didn't workout

```
df = df.sort_values(['lat', 'lon'])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
max_index = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    max_index = index
    
pair_list = pairs(len(list(df['lat'])))

cluster = -1
cluster_dict = {}

for i, j in pair_list:
    #print(i, j)
    index = i
    #stat_nr = df.loc[i]['vwbhfnrprz']
    lat = df.loc[i]['lat']
    lon = df.loc[i]['lon']
        
    index_next = j
    #stat_nr_next = df.loc[j]['vwbhfnrprz']
    lat_next = df.loc[j]['lat']
    lon_next = df.loc[j]['lon']
    distance = haversine(lon,lat, lon_next, lat_next)
    if distance <= 400:
        cluster += 1
        print('cluster ' + str(cluster))
        if len(cluster_dict) == 0:
            cluster_dict[cluster]=[i,j]
        elif len(cluster_dict) != 0:
            for k in cluster_dict.copy():
                print(cluster_dict)
                print('k '+str(k))
                print(i,j)
                if i not in cluster_dict[k]:
                    
                    cluster_dict[cluster] = [i]
                    print(cluster_dict)
                    #cluster_dict[k].append(i)
                if j not in cluster_dict[k]:
                    
                    #print(cluster_dict[k])
                    break
                if j in cluster_dict[k]:
                    break
        print(cluster, index, index_next, lat, lon,  lat_next, lon_next, distance)
```

The idea behind this was - dictionary=cluster_dict ie. pair (5,6):

- if cluster_dict was empty then 5 and 6 should be appended to
  cluster_dict with cluster = 0 --> cluster_dict = {0:[5,6]}
- if cluster_dict was not empty cluster_dict = {0:[1,2]} and 5,6 were
  not in cluster_dict  then 5 and 6 should be appended to cluster_dict
  with cluster = 1 --> cluster_dict = {0:[1,2], 1:[5,6]}
- if cluster_dict was not empty cluster_dict = {0:[1,2], 0:[4,5]} and 5
  or 6 were in cluster_dict then 5 or 6 should be appended to
  cluster_dict with cluster = cluster of existing one --> cluster_dict =
  {0:[1,2], 0:[4,5,6]}

Thanks!

Comment: you talk about "groups" in your explanation. Does it refer to the two groups '<400' and '>=400'?

Comment: no those <400 should be grouped again as all points are not always near each other, ie. 1,2 have a distance  <400 and [4,5,6] <400 but [1,2] and [4,5,6] are far away. imagine like London and Paris are near and Hong Kong and Peking --> [London, Paris] and [Hong Kong, Peking] but  [London, Paris] is far away from [Hong Kong, Peking]

Answer (score 1):

I took a different approach on some steps by utilizing pandas functionality, but that should do it.

First, from your provided data set, I created a helper dataframe that gives me a point I and the point as list.

```
points = (df
    .assign(
        id = lambda x : np.arange(len(x)),
        point = lambda x : x.apply(lambda x : 
            [x.lat, x.lon], 
            axis = 1)
    )
)
points
```

looking like this:

| lat | lon | id | point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -57.213879 | 17.916958 | 0 | `[-57.21387861213883, 17.9169583041696]` |
| 76.392039 | 0.060883 | 1 | `[76.39203948037851, 0.060882542482108504]` |
| 0.124177 | 1.041767 | 2 | `[0.12417670682730897, 1.0417670682730924]` |
| -64.840322 | 21.374279 | 3 | `[-64.8403219767877, 21.37427929614376]` |
| -48.966303 | 81.336324 | 4 | `[-48.96630293735991, 81.33632377806619]` |

Then the following steps are applied:

- expand the ids to create the pairs
- reduce pairs to unique ones
- left join the point coordinates for "from" and "to"
- calculate haversine (using your provided function)
- grouping and calcuating the mean

```
distances = (
    # create the pairs
    pd.DataFrame(index = 
        pd.MultiIndex
            .from_product(
                [points.id.to_list(), points.id.to_list()], 
                names = ["from_id", "to_id"]
            )
        )
    .reset_index()
    # reduce to unique pairs (including itself, to get single clusters later)
    # (if you imaginge this as a from-to-matrix, it takes the upper half in a
    # very simplified way)
    .query("from_id < to_id")
    # add the coordinates from the helper table (please be aware of the required renaming.
    # This would create the right id columns as additional columns you would not want if
    # this steps is the required output. You would have to .drop() them...
    .merge(
        points.filter(["id", "point"]).rename(columns={"point" : "from_point"}),
        how="left",
        left_on = "from_id",
        right_on = "id"
    )
    .merge(
        points.filter(["id", "point"]).rename(columns={"point" : "to_point"}),
        how="left",
        left_on = "to_id",
        right_on = "id"
    )
    # calculate haversine and grouping and calculating the mean (I find it confusing, 
    # that you points are (lat, lon) but your function takes (lon,lat). Better check this
    # for errors!
    .assign(
        haversine = lambda x : x.apply(lambda x : 
            haversine(x.from_point[1], x.from_point[0], x.to_point[1], x.to_point[0])
            , axis = 1),
        # !!!! important change to original
        distance_group = lambda x : (x.haversine <= 400).map({True : "< 400", False : ">= 400"}).astype('category'),
        # this avoids points showing up in smaler clusters
        already_clusterd = lambda x : x.apply(lambda y : 
            y.from_id in x.query("distance_group == '< 400' and from_id != to_id").to_id.to_list()
            , axis = 1) 
    )
    .groupby(["from_id", "distance_group"])
    .agg(cluster = ("to_id", lambda x : x.to_list()))
    .reset_index()
    )
        
print(distances)
```

This gives us the following table (example)

|  | from_id | distance_group | cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | < 400 | `[0, 7]` |
| 1 | 0 | >= 400 | `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]` |
| 2 | 1 | < 400 | `[1]` |
| 3 | 1 | >= 400 | `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]` |
| 4 | 2 | < 400 | `[2]` |
| 5 | 2 | >= 400 | `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]` |
| 6 | 3 | < 400 | `[3]` |

So, from here on, I somewhat confused on your inteded result, but this would give us the closest to what I think you want

```
(distances
    .query("distance_group == '< 400'")
    # comment the next two lines to get single length clusters
    .assign(cluter_length = lambda x : x.cluster.map(lambda x : len(x)))
    .query("cluter_length > 1")
    ).cluster.to_list()
```

without the line commented the output:
`[[0, 7], [5, 6, 9]]`
if you comment them out, the output is
`[[0, 7], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5, 6, 9], [8], [10], [11], [12]]`

Comment: thanks! how would the code be if I wanted to group all points near each other like in the edited post of mine? IN READ circle

Comment: @TheDev I changed the latter part of the answer, does that answer your question?

Comment: yes, thanks I have implemented one myself but it is slow for large datasets

Comment: @TheDev I edited it a bit such that you get the single clusters as well...

Comment: thanks, but single entry is not a cluster since it has no neighbor with distance <400, this cluster would be best [[0, 7], [5, 6, 9]]

Comment: @TheDev I agree on the cluster definition, but my intention was to give you a complete response to all points... Whether you use them or not is up to you. But now you have the opportunity :)

Comment: @TheDev now this should give you the intended solution...

Comment: thanks, is it efficient for 3.5 million pairs :D

Comment: depends... if it is 3,5 mio points that are considered in pairs, then not... but nothing would ever be... if 1870 points leading to 3,5 mio pairs it might come to a solution within reasonable time given some available RAM

Answer (score 0):

I used a nested list to do the clustering but is inefficient on large datasets:

```
df = df.sort_values(['lat', 'lon'])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
max_index = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    max_index = index
    
pair_list = pairs(len(list(df['lat'])))

cluster = -1
num_exists_list = []
cluster_list = []

for i, j in pair_list:
    #print(i, j)
    index = i
    #stat_nr = df.loc[i]['vwbhfnrprz']
    lat = df.loc[i]['lat']
    lon = df.loc[i]['lon']
        
    index_next = j
    #stat_nr_next = df.loc[j]['vwbhfnrprz']
    lat_next = df.loc[j]['lat']
    lon_next = df.loc[j]['lon']
    distance = haversine(lon,lat, lon_next, lat_next)
    if distance <= 400:
        if len(cluster_list)==0:
            num_exists_list.append(i)
            num_exists_list.append(j)
            cluster_list.append([i,j])
            #print('first - ' + str([i,j]))
        else:
            if i not in num_exists_list and j not in num_exists_list:
                num_exists_list.append(i)
                num_exists_list.append(j)
                cluster_list.append([i,j])
                #print('not exists - ' + str([i,j]))
            elif i in num_exists_list and j not in num_exists_list:
                index = find_index(cluster_list,i)
                cluster_list[index].append(j)
                num_exists_list.append(j)
                #print('exists - ' + str(i) + ' - missing ' + str(j))
            elif i not in num_exists_list and j in num_exists_list:
                index = find_index(cluster_list,j)
                cluster_list[index].append(i)
                num_exists_list.append(i)
                #print('exists - ' + str(i) + ' - missing ' + str(j))
                
print('--------------------')
#print(num_exists_list)            
print(cluster_list)
```